# Mobile application using html5 tutorial

Tags: html

I am new in this field and want to learn mobile app development using html5.. can anyone help me with some useful tutorial or link to learn this.

Answer (score 0):

I must recommend the phonegap solution, it will help you to build cross device HTML5 apps allowing you to utilize lots of the phones features:

[phonegap api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/index.html)

and

[phonegap getting started guides](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides)